# Mercurial Workflow

Tags: mercurial

I develop the same system for multiple clients and I use Mercurial as the database and codebase version control.

Workflow is typically, develop on local machine, deploy to staging for testing/QA. Then I deploy to the multiple repositories on production.
However now, I have to deploy to production this week for one client and the rest in a couple of weeks time (Have to give notice to other clients). Let's call this **version 10**. After I deploy this week, I then need to move some new code to staging for testing. Let's call this **version 11**. How to I pull to production in a couple of weeks **(version 10)** without pulling the new changes **(version 11)**?

I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Such workflow is possible if you work with separate branches, e.g. if you have in *default* branch only that code which you consider stable enough to pull to clients and all your code so far only deemed ready for testing and QA is found in a separate branch, let's call it *testing*.

Thus, if you have a repository which looks like

```
hg log -G -T"{branch}-{rev}: {desc}\n"
@  testing-4: Add some code which needs testing
|
| o  default-3: Changes to be deployed to client
| |
| o  default-2: Some stuff
|/
o  default-1: Second changeset    
|
o  default-0: First changeset
```

you then can clone or pull only the changes which are found in the *default* branch, but not in your testing one:

`hg clone --branch default`

or

`hg plull --branch default`

If you later succeed with testing your code and want to deply that also to your client, first merge the code from your *testing* branch into default and then, like above, only pull the default branch to your clients. Thus if you do all your coding in the *testing* branch and only merge to default what you want to ship, then you will only ever pull what you explicit merged to default.

Of course you could also reverse the roles of branches: develop in default and have a *production* branch which you pull to your clients.

Comment: Hi planetmaker, thanks. That makes sense. Will try it.